# Audio stream from cordova-plugin-audioinput to Google Speech API

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

For a cross-platform app project using Meteor framework, I'd like to record microphone inputs and extract speech thanks to [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/?hl=fr)

Following Google documentation, I'm more specifically trying to build an audio stream to feed the Google Speech client.

On client side, a recording button triggers the following `startCapture` function (based on [cordova audioinput plugin](https://github.com/edimuj/cordova-plugin-audioinput)):

```
export var startCapture = function () {
  try {
    if (window.audioinput && !audioinput.isCapturing()) {

      setTimeout(stopCapture, 20000);

      var captureCfg = {
        sampleRate: 16000,
        bufferSize: 2048,
      }
      audioinput.start(captureCfg);
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
}
```

`audioinput` events allow me to get chunks of audio data as it is recorded:

```
window.addEventListener('audioinput', onAudioInputCapture, false);

var audioDataQueue = [];
function onAudioInputCapture(evt) {
  try {
    if (evt && evt.data) {
      // Push the data to the audio queue (array)
      audioDataQueue.push(evt.data);

      // Here should probably be a call to a Meteor server method?
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to convert the recorded audio data to some ReadableStream, that I would pipe to Google Speech API client on server side.

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: "LINEAR16",
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
  },
 interimResults: true,
};

export const recognizeStream = client
 .streamingRecognize(request)
 .on('error', console.error)
 .on('data', data =>
   console.log(data.results)
 );
```

I tried the following approach, but it doesn't feel like the right way to proceed:

```
const Stream = require('stream')

var serverAudioDataQueue = [];
const readable = new Stream.Readable({
  objectMode: true,
});
readable._read = function(n){
  this.push(audioDataQueue.splice(0, audioDataQueue.length))
}
readable.pipe(recognizeStream);

Meteor.methods({
  'feedGoogleSpeech': function(data){
    data.forEach(item=>serverAudioDataQueue.push(item));
  },
...
});
```

Any insight on this?

Comment: How did you get on with this Kevin, did you find a solution?